# difficulties with div following cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a tooltip whenever the person hovers over an image, I've also made the tooltip follow the mouse, and the tooltip will disappear whenever the person leaves the area where the image is located. This works fine and all, but when I move the cursor to the right when the tooltip is following it, it'll start flickering. I know that the cause of this is because the cursor is leaving the image area and entering the tooltip area for a little amount of time. Got no idea how to fix this. Have a look at my code:

HTML:

```
<img id="mainImage" src="https://i1.wp.com/historiek.net/wp-content/uploads-phistor1/2015/09/Het-nieuw-logo-van-Google-e1441130561430.jpg?fit=663%2C282&ssl=1">
   <div id="toolTip">This is the logo of google</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('#mainImage').hover (
        $('#mainImage').on('mousemove', function(e) {
           $('#toolTip').css({
               'left' : e.pageX,
               'top' : e.pageY,
               'display' : 'block'
           });
        }),
        $('#mainImage').on('mouseout', function() {
            $('#toolTip').css('display', 'none');
        })
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS for this page, set [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on your tooltip:

```css
#toolTip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will cause click and hover events to be ignored, so the tooltip will no longer steal the hover event from the element underneath it.